# lua array contains specific value for checking further

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table, luafilesystem

sorry if i am bothering you now, i am still learning. but i need help. could you correct me and script how to check and then get value of array 2d for checking further and counting points ?

example array2d syntax that i build :

```
role = {{[name],[points],[indexpoint]},
        {[...],[...],[...]}}
```

example array2d value that i make :

```
role = {{"mike", 30, "1"},
        {"michael", 40, "2"},
        {"mike", 40, "2"},
        {"michael", 50, "3"},
        {"frost", 50, "3"},
        {"nick", 60, "4"}}
```

what i wanted is. when i am searching for name "michael". it will detect value in the array. something like this

```
local player_data = {{"michael", 40, "2"},{"michael", 50, "3"}}
```

so after this, i can count the points that he already have. 40+50
and the result "90" will send to new variable like `resultpoint = 90`

so the print will show like this

```
Player "Michael"
Your points is "90"
Here is the list of your index that you earned :
1. earn 40 points in index point "2"
2. earn 50 points in index point "3"
```

my long code here :

```
role = {{"mike", "30", "1"},
        {"michael", "40", "2"},
        {"mike", "40", "2"},
        {"michael", "50", "3"},
        {"frost", "50", "3"},
        {"nick", "60", "4"}}

function check_role1(tab, val)
        for index, value in ipairs (tab) do
            -- We grab the first index of our sub-table instead for player name
            if value[1] == val then
                return true
            end
        end
        return false
    end

    function check_role2(tab, val)
        for index, value in ipairs (tab) do
            -- We grab the third index of our sub-table instead for index point
            if value[3] == val then
                return true
            end
        end
        return false
    end

    function detectroles(name)
        pn = name
        if check_role1 (role, pn) then
            print ('Yep')
            --[[for i = 1, #role do
                 player_checkname[i] = role[i][1] -- Get Player Name From Array for checking further
                 player_checkpnt[i] = role[i][2] -- Get Player Point From Array for checking further
                 player_checkidpnt[i] = role[i][3] -- Get Player Point From Array for checking further]]
             -- is this correct code to get value ?
            end
        else
            print ('You dont earn any points')
        end
    end

    detectroles("jack") -- this is call function, for checking name jack if he is in array or not
```

is this really possible ? if there is a simple way or more less code, let me know. i know, it's too much code. i am still newbie

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store the players in a dictionary, where each name is equal to an array of their points? Then you have quick and easy lookups, and easy to insert scores.

Comment: Store the data like this: `local data = {Name1={score1,score2},Name2={score1,score2}}` then to access a list of every score a person owns: `data.Name1`

Comment: yeah i guess, that's better too, but i just feel complicated. the array2d, it was come from read file .txt line by line. example = `mike:30:1` . it was extracted by loop line:match `line_roles[#line_roles+1] = { line:match('([^:]+):(%d+):(%d+)') }` . so i don't really know, how it's work when with array like you said

Comment: It's far less complicated an elaborate. You should look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for are some general data structure functions known as `filter` (sometimes called `select`) and `reduce`.

---

`filter` is a simple function which operates on a set of values, creating a new set containing only those which conform to a provided predicate. The implementation of `filter` is very straight-forward:

- Create a new, empty set
- Iterate through your existing set, reading each value
- Push any values which pass the test into the new set

The result of the operation is the new set.

In Lua:

```
local function filter (list, test)
    local result = {}

    for index, value in ipairs(list) do
        if test(value, index) then
            result[#result + 1] = value
        end
    end

    return result
end
```

We can use this function to get a filtered set of values, where the first entry in each table is `'michael'`:

```
local set = {
    { "mike", "30", "1" },
    { "michael", "40", "2" },
    { "mike", "40", "2" },
    { "michael", "50", "3" },
    { "frost", "50", "3" },
    { "nick", "60", "4" }
}

local filtered_set = filter(set, function (person)
    return person[1] == 'michael'
end)

for _, person in ipairs(filtered_set) do
    print(unpack(person))
end

--[[stdout:
  michael   40  2   
  michael   50  3
]]
```

---

`reduce` is a function which accumulates a single value by iterating upon a set of values. `reduce` typically allows for a provided initial value, otherwise the initial value is the first value in the set.

In Lua:

```
local function reduce (set, action, initial_value)
    local result
    local index

    if initial_value ~= nil then
        result = initial_value
        index = 1
    else
        result = set[1]
        index = 2
    end

    for i = index, #set do
        result = action(result, set[i], i)
    end

    return result
end
```

Which we can use to determine a combined value for set entries:

```
local value = reduce(filtered_set, function (score, next_entry)
    return score + next_entry[2] -- Careful with relying on stringly-math
end, 0)

print(value) --> prints 90
```

---

Though absent from the Lua Standard Library, these are very common *functional* set operations, and learning how to implement them (and others like `each`, `map`, `reject`, `count`, `index`, `has`, `find`) will teach you a lot about working with data structures.

Try thinking about how they would fit into your current code.

Comment: yay thanks for help, can you tell me how can i get the array from person 

`for _, person in ipairs(filtered_set) do
 print(unpack(person))
end`

i need to send this array values to new like i said

`local player_data = {{"michael", 40, "2"},{"michael", 50, "3"}}`

Comment: @Han That's what `filtered_set` _is_.

Comment: oh yeah, i figured it out, before you answer.. thanks alot!